# custom google map marker - javascript & php

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-markers, google-maps

here is my code - I've tried using the google maps api and other tutorials, but I can't seem to get the code right. It either displays the default icon or no icon at all.

Here is the unaltered code -

```
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                    //<![CDATA[

                    <?php if ($er_imglayout == 4 && $row->image2) { ?>
                        function domap()
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        function ezrealtymap()
                    <?php } ?>
                    {
                        // Check to see if this browser can run the Google API
                        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

                            gmarkers = [];
                            htmls = [];
                            to_htmls = [];
                            from_htmls = [];
                            i=0;


                            // Display the map, with some controls and set the initial location 
                            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
                            map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
                            map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
                            map.setCenter(new GLatLng( <?php echo $row->declat;?>,<?php echo $row->declong;?>), <?php echo $er_mapres;?>);
                            map.setMapType(<?php echo $er_mapview;?>);

                            // Set up three markers with info windows 

                            var point = new GLatLng( <?php echo $row->declat;?>,<?php echo $row->declong;?>);
                            var marker = createMarker(point,"<?php echo stripslashes($row->adline);?>","<?php echo stripslashes($row->adline);?>")
                            map.addOverlay(marker);

                        } else {

                            // display a warning if the browser was not compatible

                            alert("<?php echo _EZREALTY_MAPPING_INCOMPATIBLE;?>");
                        }
                    }

                    // This Javascript is based on code provided by the
                    // Blackpool Community Church Javascript Team
                    // http://www.commchurch.freeserve.co.uk/   
                    // http://www.econym.demon.co.uk/googlemaps/

                    //]]>

                    // A function to create the marker and set up the event window

                    function createMarker(point,name,html) {
                        var marker = new GMarker(point);

                        // The info window version with the "to here" form open

                        to_htmls[i] = html + '<br /><?php echo _EZREALTY_MAP_DIRECTIONS;?>: <strong><?php echo _EZREALTY_MAP_TOHERE;?></strong> - <a href="javascript:fromhere(' + i + ')"><?php echo _EZREALTY_MAP_FROMHERE;?></a>' +
                        '<br /><?php echo _EZREALTY_MAP_START;?>:<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="_blank">' +
                        '<input type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" name="saddr" id="saddr" value="" /><br />' +
                        '<input value="<?php echo _EZREALTY_MAP_DIRECTIONS;?>" type="submit">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="' + point.lat() + ',' + point.lng() + 
                        // "(" + name + ")" + 
                        '"/>';

                        // The info window version with the "to here" form open

                        from_htmls[i] = html + '<br /><?php echo _EZREALTY_MAP_DIRECTIONS;?>: <a href="javascript:tohere(' + i + ')"><?php echo _EZREALTY_MAP_TOHERE;?></a> - <strong><?php echo _EZREALTY_MAP_FROMHERE;?></strong>' +
                        '<br /><?php echo _EZREALTY_MAP_END;?>:<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get"" target="_blank">' +
                        '<input type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" name="daddr" id="daddr" value="" /><br />' +
                        '<input value="<?php echo _EZREALTY_MAP_DIRECTIONS;?>" type="submit">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="saddr" value="' + point.lat() + ',' + point.lng() +
                        // "(" + name + ")" + 
                        '"/>';

                        // The inactive version of the direction info

                        html = html + '<br /><?php echo _EZREALTY_MAP_DIRECTIONS;?>: <a href="javascript:tohere('+i+')"><?php echo _EZREALTY_MAP_TOHERE;?></a> - <a href="javascript:fromhere('+i+')"><?php echo _EZREALTY_MAP_FROMHERE;?></a>';

                        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
                        });
                        gmarkers[i] = marker;
                        htmls[i] = html;
                        i++;
                        return marker;
                    }

                    // functions that open the directions forms
                    function tohere(i) {
                        gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(to_htmls[i]);
                    }
                    function fromhere(i) {
                        gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(from_htmls[i]);
                    }

                    </script>
```

Comment: looks like you're missing all your code.

Comment: Looks like the last part of the createMarker function is missing from your post.

Comment: Whoops - there, I've added the entire script - Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humm sorry - now I understand. I guess you're missing a part of the marker generation process. This is how I create custom markers and add them to the map.

```
var niceIcon = new GIcon();
niceIcon.image = '/images/Maps/icon/image.png';
niceIcon.shadow = '/images/Maps/icon/shadow.png';
niceIcon.iconSize = new GSize(34, 38);
niceIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(53, 38);
niceIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(0, 38);
niceIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(17, 0);
niceIcon.printImage = '/images/Maps/icon/printImage.gif';
niceIcon.mozPrintImage = '/images/Maps/icon/mozPrintImage.gif';
niceIcon.printShadow = '/images/Maps/icon/printShadow.gif';
niceIcon.transparent = '/images/Maps/icon/transparent.png';
niceIcon.imageMap = [27, 0, 27, 1, 27, 2, 27, 3, 27, 4, 27, 5, 27, 6, 27, 7, 27, 8, 27, 9, 27, 10, 27, 11, 27, 12, 27, 13, 27, 14, 27, 15, 27, 16, 27, 17, 27, 18, 27, 19, 27, 20, 33, 21, 33, 22, 33, 23, 33, 24, 32, 25, 32, 26, 31, 27, 30, 28, 31, 29, 30, 30, 30, 31, 17, 32, 19, 33, 18, 34, 15, 35, 15, 36, 14, 37, 13, 37, 13, 36, 12, 35, 11, 34, 11, 33, 10, 32, 3, 31, 3, 30, 3, 29, 3, 28, 0, 27, 0, 26, 0, 25, 0, 24, 0, 23, 0, 22, 0, 21, 0, 20, 0, 19, 0, 18, 0, 17, 0, 16, 0, 15, 0, 14, 0, 13, 0, 12, 0, 11, 0, 10, 0, 9, 0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0];

var markerOptions = { icon: niceIcon };

var point = new GLatLng(lat, lon);
var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Comment: that part I have under control - but integrating with my above code is where I'm having an issue

Comment: I added the same as above, but the issue I ran into was with the following code:

 var point = new GLatLng( <?php echo $row->declat;?>,<?php echo $row->declong;?>);
                            var marker = createMarker(point,"<?php echo stripslashes($row->adline);?>","<?php echo stripslashes($row->adline);?>")

how do I adapt that with the var point and var marker in the custom icon code?

Comment: In createMarker(...) you have: var marker = new GMarker(point); - there you should add a second parameter with markerOptions where you set all the info about the icon (icon: niceIcon in my code).

Comment: I still can't seem to get it to work. I'm not familiar enough with the api to combine all these variables. I'm getting conflict somewhere, because the map will either show without the marker or the map disappears altogether.

Any additional help would be appreciated. Thanks!